# Return different objects from a method, depending on whether method parameter is present

Tags: python

I am creating a class with a number of methods, as one of the steps, I want to change one of the args to call the new version in a different method from the class.

I am sure it’s something simple but I just can’t figure out where it is going wrong.

For brevity, I have tried to make a simple example from what I am actually coding.

```
class Double:
    def __init__(self, x):
        self.x = x

    def double(self):
        self.x = self.x * 2
        # change the x item to x*2
        return self.x

    def return1(self, xg=x):
        # if xg isn’t defined by user, this method should return
        # the new version of x created above
        return xg
```

I would also appreciate any other feedback on my class coding.

Comment: Some examples with expected results would help make sense of this question...

Comment: Some class coding feedback - your double method is *both* updating the object's internal value of x to be double its original value, *and* returning the doubled value. It should probably do one or the other. It mostly depends on your use case which one you should do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not clear what you are trying to accomplish and there is probably a better design, but to answer your question, you can use the following idiom:

```
def return1(self, xg=None):
    return xg if xg is not None else self.x
```